# Modifying a numpy array after conversion from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, numpy

I have the following code which I am writing as part of a simple movie recommender in python so I can mimic the results I get as part of coursera's Machine Learning Course taught by Andrew NG.

I want to modify the numpy.ndarray that I get after calling as_matrix() on the pandas dataframe and add a column vector to it like we can in MATLAB

```
Y = [ratings Y]
```

Following is my python code

```
dataFile='/filepath/'

userItemRatings = pd.read_csv(dataFile, sep="\t", names=['userId', 'movieId', 'rating','timestamp'])
movieInfoFile = '/filepath/'
movieInfo = pd.read_csv(movieInfoFile, sep="|", names=['movieId','Title','Release Date','Video Release Date','IMDb URL','Unknown','Action','Adventure','Animation','Childrens','Comedy','Crime','Documentary','Drama','Fantasy','Film-Noir','Horror','Musical','Mystery','Romance','Sci-Fi','Thriller','War','Western'], encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

userMovieMatrix=pd.merge(userItemRatings, movieInfo, left_on='movieId', right_on='movieId')
userMovieSubMatrix = userMovieMatrix[['userId', 'movieId', 'rating','timestamp','Title']]


Y = pd.pivot_table(userMovieSubMatrix, values='rating', index=['movieId'], columns=['userId'])
Y.fillna(0,inplace=True)
movies = Y.shape[0]  
users = Y.shape[1] +1 



ratings = np.zeros((1682, 1))

ratings[0] = 4  
ratings[6] = 3  
ratings[11] = 5  
ratings[53] = 4  
ratings[63] = 5  
ratings[65] = 3  
ratings[68] = 5  
ratings[97] = 2  
ratings[182] = 4  
ratings[225] = 5  
ratings[354] = 5

features = 10

theta = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(users,features))# users 943*3 
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(movies,features))# movies 1682 * 3


X = X.as_matrix()
theta = theta.as_matrix()

Y = Y.as_matrix()


"""want to insert a column vector into this Y to get a new Y of dimension 
   1682*944, but only seeing 1682*943 after the following statement

"""
np.insert(Y, 0, ratings, axis=1)

R = Y.copy()
R[R!=0] = 1





Ymean = np.zeros((movies, 1))  
Ynorm = np.zeros((movies, users))



for i in range(movies):  
    idx = np.where(R[i,:] == 1)[0]
    Ymean[i] = Y[i,idx].mean()
    Ynorm[i,idx] = Y[i,idx] - Ymean[i]

print(type(Ymean), type(Ynorm), type(Y), Y.shape)
Ynorm[np.isnan(Ynorm)] = 0.
Ymean[np.isnan(Ymean)] = 0.
```

There is an inline comment inserted, but my problem is when I create a new numpy array and call insert, it works just fine. However the numpy array I get after calling [as_matrix()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) on pandas dataframe on which [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) is called doesn't work. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` does not operate in place, you need to assign the output to a variable. Try:

```
Y = np.insert(Y, 0, ratings, axis=1)
```